# Calling functions from a script using argparse without using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, argparse

I have been given an existing script (let's call it existing.py) that in its MVCE form has the following structure.

```py
import argparse

FLAGS = None
def func():
  print(FLAGS.abc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--abc',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='abc.'
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  func()
```

As this is part of tool that gets constantly updated, I cannot change existing.py. Normally, existing.py is invoked with commandline arguments.

```
python -m existing.py --abc "Ok"
```

which prints the output 'Ok'.

I wish to call the functions (not the whole script) in existing.py using another script. How can I feed in the FLAGS object that is used in the functions of the script? I do not wish to use subprocess will just run the script in its entirety.

I know that argparse creates the FLAGS as a Namespace dictionary and I can construct it in calling.py (see code below) but I cannot then push it back into the function that is imported from existing.py into calling.py. The following is the calling.py that I've tried.

```
from existing import func
import argparse
args = argparse.Namespace()
args.abc = 'Ok'
FLAGS = args
func()
```

which throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'abc'
```

This is different from other StackOverflow questions as this question explicitly forbids subprocess and the existing script cannot be changed.

Comment: Even though you imported `func`, it 'sees' the `FLAGS` defined in `existing`.  If you defined `func` to take `FLAGS` as an argument, rather than global, `def func(FLAGS): ...`, then you could call it with `func(FLAGS)` in `existing`, or with `func(args)` in `calling`.

Comment: Not that it affects your error, but you could define `args = argparse.Namespace(abc='OK')`.

Comment: @hpaulj, it doesn't seem like there's much that can be done except change the existing.py. This is a MVCE but the actual existing.py runs into thousands of lines and FLAGS appear in many functions. What do you think is the most minimal way of changing existing.py so that I can call it with calling.py and still feed in FLAGS into the functions?

Comment: I'd try importing `existing` and setting `existing.FLAGS = args`.  That idea is to try to set the `FLAGS` variable in the imported namespace.  If it doesn't work you may need to ask a new question with a focus on setting and using an imported module's global.  `argparse` isn't important to this issue.

Comment: @hpaulj, that actually works for the MVCE. I am going to try it for my actual use case. Thanks. Do you want to write up the one-liner so I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `existing` and use

```
existing.FLAGS = args
```

Now functions defined in the `existing` namespace should see the desired `FLAGS` object.